# No result when using getElementById on a span id

Tags: javascript, html

I need to get the current width of an image, so I tried my hand at some javascript. Note, I'm working on Zen Cart, so adding classes to img src is not an option as images are output using code such as

```
<?php echo zen_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . $categories_image, '', SUBCATEGORY_IMAGE_TOP_WIDTH, SUBCATEGORY_IMAGE_TOP_HEIGHT); ?>
```

So I wrapped the image in a span so that it would be the same width as the image like this.

```
<span id="imageContainer">
  <?php echo zen_image(DIR_WS_IMAGES . $categories_image, '', SUBCATEGORY_IMAGE_TOP_WIDTH, SUBCATEGORY_IMAGE_TOP_HEIGHT); ?>
</span
```

The relevant line in my javascript is

```
imageSize = document.getElementById("imageContainer").clientWidth;
```

If I output to console.log it returns 0

However, if I change the span to

```
<div id="imageContainer">
```

then it correctly returns the size of the image, however, I can't use a div as that extends beyond the size of the image once the viewport increases beyond the width of the image.

So the question is, why doesn't `document.getElementById` work on a `span`, and is there a way around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[`.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)** does indeed work on a **[`<span>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span)** element, the problem is that **[`.clientWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth)** does not. This is because `<span>` is an [**inline** element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements), and thus has no set **[`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)** or **[`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height)**. **[`<div>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div)** is a [**block-level** element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements), so has a default `width`, which is why you can output it with JavaScript.

This can be seen in the following:

```js
var span = document.getElementById('example');
console.log(span.innerHTML);
console.log(span.clientWidth);

var div = document.getElementById('example2');
console.log(div.innerHTML);
console.log(div.clientWidth);
```

```html
<span id="example">Span</span>
<div id="example2">Div</div>
```

Comment: Nicely answered, much better reply than my own - points up given

Answer (score 3):

This is because `span` is an inline element and div is a `block` element.

And in the documentation of [Element.clientWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth) it is clearly mentioned that

> The Element.clientWidth property is zero for elements with no CSS or
>   inline layout boxes, otherwise it's the inner width of an element in
>   pixels. It includes padding but not the vertical scrollbar (if
>   present, if rendered), border or margin.

Answer (score 2):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth:

> The Element.clientWidth property is zero for elements with no CSS or
>   inline layout boxes

Ues the [offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth) property instead, which *does* work on inline elements:

```js
var s = document.getElementById('imageContainer');

console.log(s.offsetWidth);
```

```html
<span id="imageContainer">
  This is a test
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Summary**
You are stating you are getting no results when you perform a getElementById

**Issue**
You have already gathered you needed to change the element over from a SPAN tag to DIV, this is a common mistake many make.

Its important to know a SPAN tag is intended to contain text only and used to primarily add styling to a section of a paragraph such as:

```
<p>
   Welcome to stackoverflow, an <span>online community</span> of developers
</p>
```

This will allow you to specifically format online community using CSS or highlight the text etc

A Div element can contain more than just text and therefore will bring back additional results when queried

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span